# Optimistic version locking

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using spring orm with hibernate.I have a method as follows

Object has version column .@Version.

```
    void processObject(){
      Object obj = getObjectFromDB(int id);
      //do lot of processing. Takes 15 min
     //version number is not changed    
     //if some other object updates the same object , which
     //exception is thrown when folloing code runs
     updateObject(obj) ; 
     //
    }

    @Transactional
    updateObject(Object object){
     session.save(object)
    }

    @Transcational
    Object getObjectFromDB(int id){

    }
```

Now if some other thread updates the object while i process and save the object,then which exception will be thrown ?

```
1)StaleStateException (hibernate)
2)StaleObjectstateException (hibernate)
3)ConcurrentFailureException (spring)
4)Any other?
```

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying orm (hibernate), will throw

```
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException
```

Then spring data access tier will catch it, and wrap it in

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException
```

So the stacktrace you will get will be:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: 
    Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException:
```

You can read about [hibernate optimistic locking](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html) and [spring exception translation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/dao.html)

Comment: when is this exception thrown then http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/dao/ConcurrencyFailureException.html

Comment: ConcurrencyFailureException is super class for HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException. See here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException.html